how to solve System.IO.InvalidDataException: An error occurred while applying transformation to 'Web.config'?
When I install AspNet.Mvc package to my project : I found this issue System.IO.InvalidDataException: An error occurred while applying transformation to 'Web.config' in project 'Source()' No element in the source document matches '/configuration/runtime' ---> Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.XmlNodeException: No element in the source document matches '/configuration/runtime'
I have been install / uninstall all of the packages from my project and changed web.config  but not working.
